# How to generate bing map with pushpin via dynamic Url

Tags: c#, bing-maps, bing

I'm having trouble getting a pushpin to show up via the bing collection on a dynamically generated url...

I'm generating the following url from c#:

```
https://www.bing.com/maps/embed?h=300&w=300&cp=47.64005~-122.1298&style=h&lvl=15&sp=adr.1%20Microsoft%20Way%2C%20Redmond%2C%20WA%2098052
```

C# code:

```
const string mapTemplate = "https://www.bing.com/maps/embed?h=300&w=300&cp={0}~{1}&style=h&lvl=15&sp=adr.{2}";
```

Is this possible? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The embedded maps exposed by the Bing Maps consumer site do not allow you to add pushpins to the map. Use the Bing Maps developer API's, those are meant for custom apps.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712542.aspx

http://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Bummer, thanks for the answer, I'll load up the SDK.

Comment: The site used to have a pushpin, but too many people were abusing it and using it in line of business apps.